# How to convert function from Oracle to Postgres?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, postgresql

I have these tables and types in Oracle are:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE edificioty AS OBJECT(
 idf INT)

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE lettorety AS OBJECT(
pidreader_id NUMBER,
descrizione VARCHAR2(100),
edificio REF edificioty)

CREATE TABLE EDIFICIO OF EDIFICIOTY(IDF PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE LETTORE OF LETTORETY(PIDREADER_ID PRIMARY KEY);
```

I need to use them in PostreSQL, so I converted them as follows(Hope they are right):

```
CREATE TYPE edificioty AS(
 idf INTEGER)

CREATE TYPE lettorety AS(
pidreader_id INTEGER,
descrizione VARCHAR(100),
edificio edificioty)

CREATE TABLE EDIFICIO OF EDIFICIOTY(PRIMARY KEY(IDF));

CREATE TABLE LETTORE OF LETTORETY(PRIMARY KEY(PIDREADER_ID));
```

There is also this Oracle function

```
create or replace procedure populate_lettore
as
    edificio_selezionato ref edificioty;
    cursor c is select ref(e) from edificio e;
begin
    open c;
    loop
        fetch c into edificio_selezionato;
        exit when c%notfound;

        insert into lettore 
        values(lettorety(0,'Descrizione...',edificio_selezionato));
    end loop;
    close c;
end;
```

How can I convert it into Postgres?

Comment: Your converted code is not valid. Please read the postgres documentation (freely available online) to find out how to create types, tables, and functions.

Comment: Why do you say it isn't valid? I have ran it and it works.

Comment: Have you created your own types called "number" and "varchar2"? Because they don't exist in postgres.

Comment: You're right! There was some mistakes due to copy and paste. I fixed them.

Comment: @blue-phoenox  on stack i feel some time people are more comportable to vote down then to support. Like they are here to just vote down.. even they dont have anymeanfull support to somebody but they votedown to them who have. Strange isn't it.

Comment: @blue-phoenox We are here to support not for spoon feeding like baby